# WI Fi Conected server not found 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking

help here Im new on this system, i have been using version 12.04 for about a year along with windows XP on a Dell GX 680, i finally decide last week to get rid of windows completely and upgrade to 14.04, everything looks fine except WI_FI which looks good it connects to my routed and when i connect to FireFox it open my start page and after that nothing, every single page i try to open comes back with the server not found screen.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a DNS problem. Have you tried to ping to your router and see if you have contact with it and can send packets?

### Example

In terminal write e.g: `$ ping 192.168.1.1`(IP-adress for my router.) If you don't know your router IP-address, you can check it by writing `$ route -n` in the terminal and see it under "Gateway". To stop it you simply press CTRL+C.

If it works you should see something like this:

`PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=3.778 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=4.042 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=4.112 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 3.778/5.581/11.009/2.743 ms`

### Changing DNS/Adding a DNS server

I'm going to use google's DNS server for this. You should too.

To change your DNS server you should edit the `base` file under `resolv.conf.d`.

To edit the file you can do as follow:

`$ sudo vim /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base`

Add the nameservers for the file by pressing `i` and then type in:

`nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4`

press ESC key and enter `:x` to save the file.

Update `resolvconf` by typing

`$ sudo resolvconf -u`

this command tell resolvconf to regenerate the resolve file.

I hope this works for you!

**References**

- [Persist dns nameserver for ubuntu 14.04](http://www.netroby.com/view.php?id=3630#.VBymjit_t69)
- [How do I set my DNS on Ubuntu 14.04?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128220/how-do-i-set-my-dns-on-ubuntu-14-04)